# how to find number of files opened in tomcat sever

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

My application runs on Tomcat 5.5 and it opens a text file which is not closed and after a certain number of files opened server hangs up and throws an error java.io.IOException: Too many open files and works properly once I restarted the Tomcat, I have found the root cause and closed the text file using FileInputStream.close()

can any one help me to find number of files opened before the server hangs up.

Answer (score 1):

As the system level, on Linux, you can use `lsof`.  Example (replace TOMCAT_PID with the process Id of your Tomcat process)

```
lsof -p TOMCAT_PID
```

And if you know more specifically what you're looking for, just grep for it:

```
lsof -p TOMCAT_PID | grep /path/to/somewhere
```

EDIT: I've never used it, but on Windows I'd try something like this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Hi,I am running of windows

Comment: @SumanKumarGadhiraju So maybe you should include that in the tags of your question?

Comment: "Hi,I am running of windows" - that is unfortunate, but see my edit.